# Simplify table code in EaselJs

Tags: javascript, for-loop, easeljs

I've got a 2x3 table that I'm adding to EaselJS...currently I'm building it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if(i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5) {
       var xPos = playersBoxW;
    } else { 
       var xPos = 0;
    }
    if(i == 2 || i == 3) { 
       var yPos = playersBoxH;
    } else if (i == 4|| i == 5) { 
       var yPos = playersBoxH*2;
    } else { 
       var yPos = 0;
    }
    playerBox[i] = new createjs.Container().set({x: xPos, y: yPos});
}
```

It just seems a very inefficient way of doing it and not useful if the table grows. Anyone else have an idea to simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to do row/column math, there is an easier way.

Here is your original example (with some code to make it work) http://jsfiddle.net/u3ds24y5/

You can just derive the column and row with a simple equation. This lets you change the number of columns and total count easily.

```
var column = i % num_columns;
var row = Math.floor(i / num_columns);
var x = column * column_width;
var y = row * row_height;
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u3ds24y5/1/

Simplified code:

```
var cols = 2, total = 6; // Change these
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var xPos = i % cols * playersBoxW,
        yPos = Math.floor(i/cols) * playersBoxH;
    // Create container, etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I think this algorithm is essentially what it boils down to:

`xPos` seems to be equal to the integer division of `i` (by table width) times `playersBoxW`. e.g if `i = 3` and width is 2, then `xPos` is equal to `playersBoxW` times int division of `3/2` which is 1.

`yPos` seems to be equal to the integer division of `i` (by table height) times `playersBoxH`. e.g if `i = 4` and height = 3, then `yPos` is equal to `playersBoxH` times int division of `4/3` which is 1.

```
function integerDivision(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(a / b);
}

function makeTable(width, height, player, arr) {
     var xPos, yPos, size = width*height;
     for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          xPos = player.boxW  * integerDivision(i, width);
          yPos = player.boxH  * integerDivision(i, height);
          arr[i] = new createjs.Container().set({x: xPos, y: yPos});
     }
     return arr;
}
```

Integer division is like regular division but you throw the remainder away. So in this case we round the number down:
`3/2 = 1.5` => `floor` the result (round down) => `1`

---

**Side node:** *EaslJS containers can be expensive sometimes so be careful with them.*

> Containers have some overhead, so you generally shouldn't create a Container to hold a single child. [[easljs doc]](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html)

Comment: The cost of a container is relatively nominal -- the doc clarification is just that you shouldn't add one if you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks @PeterTheLobster. Great answer. I ended up using Lanny's above, but this one was very helpful too. I took your warning about not using to many containers. Keeping the references in an array allows me to pretty much skip the container anyways. :-)